# What should we do with [descriptor]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, the tag [descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/descriptor) is a bit of a mess.  It has questions about C/Unix file descriptors and questions about Python's descriptor protocol, and those things have nothing to do with each other.  I also spotted some questions involving other languages.  It seems to me we have at least two separate topics here, maybe more.  Should we split the tag, or just burninate?

**EDIT**: I recently noticed the [properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/properties) tag, which appears to cover Python descriptors and possibly some of the other languages as well.  We may need to do some retagging.

Comment: good catch Kevin... I'd say - we should split it off. Both topics are deserving of a tag, which should be clearly described.

Comment: `property` in python is *one use-case for descriptors is Python*. Methods are another common use. Please don't lump them together. If there is going to be a retagging can we at least use `python-descriptors` and `python-property` (two separate tags)?

Comment: There are also nearly 10k posts with [tag:property], you are not simply going to tease that tag apart. I'm fine with the tag use there as it is, personally.

Comment: File descriptor posts should be retagged to using [tag:file-descriptor].

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The tag is not using the word the same way we use it in Python.  I'm well aware you can use Python's descriptor syntax for a lot of different things (e.g. Django's models), but they all fall under the *syntactic construct* which the tag [tag:properties] references.

Comment: @Kevin: I disagree on that point. Functions are descriptors, but not properties, for example.

Comment: I've retagged all *file descriptor* posts to [tag:file-descriptor]; most, if not all of these were tagged with [tag:file], which I removed in that case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I disagree with your disagreement.  Functions are properties, as the tag wiki defines them.

Comment: I'm removing any use of the tag where the OP talks about *descriptions* instead.

Comment: @Kevin: by the strict definition in the tag wiki, functions can be described as properties. In Python, the difference is material and retagging all descriptor questions to [tag:property] would be counter-productive.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I don't understand.  Why are we giving Python special treatment on this?

Comment: Because in that language the devs ran with the concept and made it something far more useful? Because developers using the Python concept don't have to fit into the same mold other languages have created by using the same label? Why should all languages be treated equally as if the term means exactly the same thing in all communities?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Everyone and their dog ran with the iterator concept and turned it into something useful, and a slightly different something in each language.  Should we not have [tag:iterator] as a tag?

Comment: @Kevin: and you lost me. Not certain now what you are arguing for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69628/discussion-between-kevin-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: Descriptors also exist in computer vision ("visual descriptors", "image descriptors"). Some questions use the tag with this meaning, often together with tags such as "opencv", "computer-vision" or "image-processing".